# invalidate() does not clear session in symfony2 controller

Tags: symfony

I want to destroy a session in one of my Symfony2 controllers and am using following code:

```
$this->get('session')->invalidate();
```

But it appears that this does not in fact get rid of the session data and I have to manually remove session variables like so:

```
$session->remove('viewed');
$session->remove('name');
```

Is there a way I can troubleshoot why invalidate() does not clear the session?

P.S. If I do:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

It works, so it's not a server/php/browser issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->get('session')->clear();
```

If that doesn't work you could use this:

```
$session = $this->get('session');
$ses_vars = $session->all();
foreach ($ses_vars as $key => $value) {
    $session->remove($key);
}
```

Comment: That worked, but is there a reason why invalidate() does not work? It says in docs that that's what should be used instead of session_destroy() and I'd like to know why it won't work

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work for you, your code looks fine. Though `$this->get('session')->invalidate();` works for me using the exact same code you posted in you question. You should try updating symfony using composer: `php composer.phar update` if you havent already.

Comment: Just ran into this using S2.2 Beta 2.  Checking the return code from invalidate shows that it has failed.  I guess I need to dig into the session object.

Comment: php function session_regenerate_id(true); is failing.  Hard to track from there.  No knew session file is generated and no new value for the session cookie.  W7 xampp development mode.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you have a session to invalidate in your script.

```
$session->start();      // Start the session...
$session->invalidate(); // ...then invalidate
```

Answer (score 6):

It does work as follows:

```
$request->getSession()->invalidate(1);
```

As invalidate leaves the current session untouched if you are not providing any parameter you have to set the lifetime on 1 (one second)

http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html#method_invalidate

Comment: Just as a note since this was originally about Symfony 2: I had the same issue with Symfony 6.3, and this is still how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a custom session name start the session with that name first before invalidating it to successfully clear it.

```
$session = $this->get('session');

$session->setName('session_name');
$session->start();
$session->invalidate();
```